# Boas Práticas na Model do Codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me dizer se trabalhar com esse esqueleto na model

usar um método para listar e mostrar apenas um dado ? é correto

gostaria de opiniões pois estou aprendendo agora a trabalhar com codeigniter.

Comment: Não é necessariamente errado/certo, mas o ideal é que cada método (function) tivesse uma responsabilidade única, o seu save() faz tanto o insert e o update, seria bacana se fossem separados, pra facilitar até sua manutenção

Comment: Entendi mas qual seria a dificuldade de dar manutenção neste caso ja que o mesma função seria alterada em apenas um lugar ?? desculpe ainda estou aprendendo php e boas práticas e gostaria de saber a fundo como funciona

Comment: A ideia é que: se você precisar alterar o comportamento/regras ou validações ao inserir (insert), você só precisa alterar o seu método insert(), e não precisa ficar fazendo vários ifs dentro save(), a medida que sua aplicação vá crescendo a tendência é isso acontecer, não que isso vá acontecer obrigatoriamente neste sistema que você está trabalhando agora, mas seria o ideal

Comment: obrigado isso ajudou a entender melhor, como funciona